# Endpoint in node.js that receives a file and stores it locally

Tags: node.js, file-transfer

How can I create a endpoint in node.js (localhost:8000/file) that receives files and stores them somewhere locally.

Comment: [Minimum effort](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=node.js+upload+file) please.

Comment: Didn't find anything specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upload a file using node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926719/how-do-i-upload-a-file-using-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use multer npm module for this

Write a middleware named `upload.js` in express which will upload your file to your server

**upload.js**

```
    const multer = require('multer');
    const maxSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
      },
    
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
      },
    });
    const upload = multer({
      storage: storage
    });
    
    module.exports = upload;
```

This will upload your file to your server.You need to call it in your route

**app.js**

```
  const upload = require('./upload.js')
  router.post("/files", upload.single('file'), (req,res)=>{
    console.log("This is file ",req.file)
  });
```

Make a folder named uploads and all files will be in uploads folder.